# How do you insert multiple documents and update them the duplicates using mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to insert multiple documents using **insertMany** but few of the documents are duplicate. For those documents, I want to update them. For example:

These are the user answer documents:

```js
var useranswers = [
  { userid: 1, question: 1, answer: 10},
  { userid: 2, question: 1, answer: 1},
  { userid: 3, question: 1, answer: 11}
]

await UserQuestions.insertMany(useranswers);
```

Whenever a user enters answers for the questions, I want to update that answer if it has already been inserted.How do we achieve this using mongoose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a document, or update if it already exists, you can use `update` method with `upsert` option.

In you case :

```
UserQuestions.update(
    {userid: 1, question: 1}, // Update where userid == 1 and question == 1
    {$set: {userid: 1, question: 1, answer: 10}}, // Set userid = 1, question = 1, answer = 10
    {upsert: true} // Create if it doesnt exists
);
```

Do update multiple documents, you can imagine something like this :

```
var useranswers = [
    { userid: 1, question: 1, answer: 10},
    { userid: 2, question: 1, answer: 1},
    { userid: 3, question: 1, answer: 11}
];

for (var useranswer of useranswers) {
    UserQuestions.update(
        {userid: useranswer.userid, question: useranswer.question},
        {$set: {userid: useranswer.userid, question: useranswer.question, answer: useranswer.answer}},
        {upsert: true}
    );
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This would be the last resort to update them in the loop. There is no other way?

Comment: And in the example above, why do you have to set userid as 1 if it's already in the where clause

Comment: You have to set userid as 1 because it will set this value if the document doesn't exists

Comment: There is no way to update multiple documents in a simple request, with differents values to set, depending of the document.